# Reference request: regularity of functionals on the space of probability measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis

Let $\mathcal M=\mathcal M(\mathbb R^d)$ be the space of finite measures on $\mathbb R^d$, and  $\mathcal P=\mathcal P(\mathbb R^d)\subset\mathcal M$ be the space of probability measures. Let $F:\mathcal P\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a concave function. I'm seeking some reference on the regularity of $\mu\longmapsto F(\mu)$. In particular, is it possible do define the derivative "$F'$" (w.r.t. some suitable topology), where we notice that $\mathcal P$ is not a vector space.

Any suggestions or comments are welcom! Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is straightforward would be to extend $F$ to the full space $\mathcal{M}$ of signed measures by setting $F(\mu) = -\infty$ if $\mu$ is not a probability measure. This extension would preserve concavity and would allow for the notion of the superdifferential and supergradients (I don't know if these notions are used - what I mean is the adaption of subdifferential and subgradients to the concave case).